# Símbolo de Moneda en itextsharp

Tags: vb.net, vb, itextsharp

estoy intentando colocar el símbolo ₡ en un PDF generado con itextsharp en VB .NET, pero el símbolo no aparece:

```
Public Sub PRUEBA_PDF()
    Dim fileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() & ".pdf"
    Dim document As New Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25)
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))

    document.Open()
    document.Add(New Paragraph("ABC₡DEF₡GHI"))
    document.Close()

    Dim prc As Process = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
    prc.StartInfo.FileName = fileName
    prc.Start()
End Sub
```

*PERO LA SALIDA DA: ABCDEFGHI

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! podra ser un problema de codificacion del componente? que no acepte esa clase de caracteres? te fijaste algo al respecto?? probaste con otros caracteres raros?

Comment: Puedes ver esto esta en java, pero puedes usar la misma lógica para tu aplicación: https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/font-examples/showing-special-characters y esta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950338/itextsharp-and-special-characters-slovak-graphemes

Comment: Gracias, por lo que veo el componente tiene esa limitante, creo que usaré un sustituto: ₡ -> ¢ el símbolo de centavos es muy parecido al que quiero utilizar, así que digamos que ese truco visual resuelve el problema, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu caso es muy parecido al de este enlace [Enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950338/itextsharp-and-special-characters-slovak-graphemes) y precisamente para que se puede imprimir un carácter como el que tu deseas imprimir tendrías que usar una fuente que permita imprimir glifos, por lo que a tu código bastará con agregar estas líneas de codigo:

```
Dim fuente As String = "c:/windows/fonts/arialbd.ttf"
Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(fuente, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)
```

e instanciar la fuente dentro de tu código

```
document.Add(New Paragraph("ABC₡DEF₡GHI", New Font(bf)))
```

por lo que finalmente tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
Public Sub PRUEBA_PDF()
        Dim fuente As String = "c:/windows/fonts/arialbd.ttf"
        Dim bf As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(fuente, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)

        Dim fileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() & ".pdf"
        Dim document As New Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25)
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))

        document.Open()    
        document.Add(New Paragraph("ABC₡DEF₡GHI", New Font(bf)))    
        document.Close()

        Dim prc As Process = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
        prc.StartInfo.FileName = fileName
        prc.Start()
    End Sub
```

Nota: para que no se imprima en negritas reemplaza `arialbd.ttf` por `arial.ttf`

Espero te sirva para futuros caracteres que desees imprimir.

Comment: Esa solución es muy elegante! es perfecta, mil gracias! No te imaginas lo que había buscado eso...

Comment: Si la respuesta fue útil considera Votarla y/o Aceptarla para futuras consultas [Aquí una referencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)